# Firebase Authentication 403 in production but works fine with localhost

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-authentication

Firebase authentication works just fine in localhost, but in a google cloud run project in production it fails with just a 403, no details of why the error

Here is the headers:

```
> POST /api/account/auth2/ HTTP/2 Host: appsite.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
> (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0
> Accept: */* Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip,
> deflate, br Referer: https://appsite.com/ Content-Type:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 X-CSRFToken:
> 6cpDY8qOBRK9XqfWcuLX6eujG85AmOnHp...b5f0j0t7tHy5rmAWCcEDw
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Content-Length: 1251 Origin:
> https://appsite.com Connection: keep-alive Cookie:
> csrftoken=6cpDY8qOBRK9XqfWcuLX6eujG85AmOnHpi4IR9rRd...Hy5rmAWCcEDw
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
> TE: trailers
```

And yes I have the domain name added in the firebase auth domains.
Any help here will be great.

I am using the google gloud python google-auth=2.3.3

```
decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(token)
 uid = decoded_token["uid"]
```

And my Javascript: const provider = new
firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

```
$('.googleLogin').click(async function () {

    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    // [START auth_google_provider_scopes]
    const credential = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
    const idToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();

    // Send Token to Back End
    return handleMethod(idToken)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a CSRF verification failed.
I had to use postman to figure out what was happening.
In case someone else faces the same problem.

> - ## Forbidden (403)
> - CSRF verification failed.    Request aborted.